# Is there a way to print only the needed elements in a list?

Tags: python

*I was solving a question from [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem) on Nested Lists.
I don't how to continue my code.*

**This is my algorithm**

1. create a list for names and marks
2. create a list for marks
3. then sort them in ascending order
4. then remove the duplicates
5. now the second element in the list is the second lowest mark
6. now from the list where names and marks are included at the start, remove the duplicates
7. then create a new list which contains only the names of the students who got second lowest marks
8. sort them in alphabetical order
9. then print the list that contains the names of the students

**This is my code**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(int(raw_input())):
        name = raw_input()
        score = float(raw_input())

student_score.append([name, score])
marks.append([score])
marks.sort()
res = []
for score in marks:
    if score not in res:
        res.append(score)
for score in res:
    second_mark = res[2]
for elements in student_score = res[2]:
        new.append(name,score)
for i in new:
    if i not in new:
        new_names.append(name)
print(sorted(new_names))
```

Comment: Indentation in Python starts in 0. So `res[2]` is the third value.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `for elements in student_score = res[2]:`?

Comment: Please, add an example of the input: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't work with separate lists for the marks and names - there has to be some kind of relationship. A dictionary will help.

Each key in the dictionary can be a score. Each associated value is a list of names (with the same score).

Once you've built the dictionary, remove the key with the lowest value.

That means that the lowest remaining key is actually the second lowest score.

Sort the associated list and print.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = dict()
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        data.setdefault(score, []).append(name)
    del data[min(data)]
    for name in sorted(data[min(data)]):
        print(name)
```

**Note:**

```
Python 3
```